# Show names once on a dual carriageway in Tilemill

Tags: tilemill

I am trying to render a local map using OSM data with Tilemill.

The biggest issue is having road names show up twice for a dual carriageway.

I was thinking I could use oneway="1" plus another selector to have it only render on "odd" streets but could not figure a way to make this work.

Here is my css:

```
#osm.roads[type="trunk"],
#osm.roads[type="primary"] {
  ::label {
    text-name: [name];
    text-face-name: 'Droid Sans Regular';
    text-placement: line;
    text-size: 15;
    text-dy: 12;
    text-halo-fill: fadeout(white, 30%);
    text-halo-radius: 2.5;
    text-max-char-angle-delta: 17;
    text-min-distance: 5;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [text-clip: false](https://www.mapbox.com/carto/api/2.3.0/#text-clip) for ::label

Comment: That prevented "Apalachee Parkway" from clipping, but it still shows up twice.